# How to debug VB6 ActiveX component?

Tags: vb6, activex-exe

I have a VB6 ActiveX EXE which is being called from another desktop application. When I launch my desktop application, I can see the ActiveX exe listed in the process manager. How do I debug this ActiveX component from within the VB6 IDE?

Comment: So you want to attach VS6 debugger to running .exe like VS20XX? I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Did the ActiveX EXE get created with PDB files?  If so you can use Visual Studio to attach a debugger to the ActiveX EXE and then load the PDBs.  Once loaded you can open the source code to of related to the ActiveX EXE and place break points were desired.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Load your ActiveX exe project into the vb6 IDE.  Set your breakpoints as desired.  Press F5 (or use the mouse to click the start button icon).

Then start the desktop application.  When it instantiates your application, it'll connect to the copy running in the IDE.  Note that you will not see the ActiveX exe show up in task manager.

Comment: No, that didn't work.. When I launched desktop application it invoked ActiveX directly, didn't hit breakpoint in the VB6 IDI.

Comment: Is the project compatibility set to binary compatibility?  With the compatibility target being the same version/interface as what the desktop application is instantiating?  If not, then you would see the behavior you are describing (the desktop app will end up instantiating the exe, not your project in the running IDE).

Comment: Let me explain what I did.1) Loaded ActiveX project into vb6 IDE  2) Set binary compatibility path where the ActiveX  exe resides. 2) put break point on main method and press F5( Let me explain why did I put breakpoint before hitting F5 because If I didn't put break point then application will through the error about command line argument that is expecting from the calling application.) 3) launched desktop application. so desktop application invoked ActiveX exe not the ActiveX control which is opened through VB6 IDE.

Comment: Command line?  You don't have a command line when an ActiveX exe is instantiated via COM/ActiveX.  Is your desktop application shell-ing or Process.Start-ing or similarly starting your exe?  If so, then it's not running as an ActiveX in this manner, you could compile as a standard exe and the desktop app could still run your exe. If this is the situation, then, no, you can't debug your app while running it from the desktop app. You can run your exe in the IDE with the command line parms to debug, no need for the desktop app then. But it's not entirely clear to me now what you are doing.

Comment: Or - you maybe have to set the start mode for the component. Select Project-Properties, Component tab and select 'ActiveX Component' instead of 'Standalone'. Then when F5 is pressed to start the program, it will wait for the program to be instantiated (by the desktop app).

Comment: @adadotnet, based on your previous comment, I asume that MarkL's answer solved your problem. Since, you are a relatively new user and none of your questions on this site has been marked as answered, I assume you might not know that you should normally mark such answer with a green checkmark to accept it. To do that, simply click the grey checkmark beside the question.

Answer (score 0):

We have to unregister the ActiveX exe from all the places and make sure there is no entry in the registry.

Search registry with activex exe name,If there is any entry in registry delete it manually.

Otherwise test application will trigger the activex instead of the one that is running from IDE